# Flutter webview text selection handle color

Tags: android, flutter, webview, textselection, flutterwebviewplugin

We have a text editing functionality in which we load HTML page in an Flutter Web-view.
The long press on text opens text selection handles,However i want to change the selection handle turquoise color(that two bubbles before and after text selection).
I have tried changing color in android styles but it didn't worked.
please note i want to change this in web view.

[image]

Comment: @Dude webview_flutter: ^1.0.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just if anyone is looking for answer,
I have found it.

Just add this line in app theme inside **styles.xml**

```
<item name="android:colorControlActivated">#YourColorString</item>
```

and it will show expected color

Comment: Just tried it and it did not work for flutter_webview

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
MaterialApp(
      title: 'title',
      theme: ThemeData(
        textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
          selectionColor: primaryColor.withOpacity(.5),
          cursorColor: primaryColor.withOpacity(.6),
          selectionHandleColor: primaryColor.withOpacity(1),
        ),
      ),
      home: Home(),
    )
```